# How to change display name for users in SharePoint Foundation (non-Domain Users)...?

Tags: sharepoint

I've added some users to my SharePoint Foundation site from the local machine.  The site is not on a domain.

The display name is always the user's account name in the form [COMPUTER\AccountName] instead of the full name that has been set up for them in the system.

Is there a way to change this through SharePoint somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the property "display name" in the user profiles should be enough.

Comment: I'm able to change the 'Full Name' property of a user through the Users property page.  Not sure if 'Display Name' is used the same with local user accounts as it is with Active Directory accounts.